# Add name(textView) to gridView list items?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gridview

How can I add name to each gridview list of items ?

for example :-

[image]

I have some items and I want to show there names at bottom of each list item.

Anybody have any idea how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want, if you make it into a View and pass that into your Adapter. So figure out how to put your image/text overlay into an XML View, and do something [like this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(context,R.layout.image_with_text);
```

It seems likely that you will actually need to write a class that extends ArrayAdapter (Or CursorAdapter) to do what you want. In that case, extend the layout, and populate your view in `getView()`. Something like this would work.

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView==null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_with_text);
    }
    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImage(getImage(position));
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(getText(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
// String[] items = {"list", "of", "items"}; -> I am using a string list. You will have to use your object list.
// setContentView(R.layout.viewWithGrid); -> whatever layout has the gridview in it
GridView g=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid); 
g.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cell, items));
```

Now you need to define your "cell.xml" layout which will have a LinearLayout that contains a TextView and an ImageView inside another linear layout (it looks like you are using images) as children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent Linear Layout> <!-- fill in attributes -->
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14dip"
/>
</ Parent Linear Layout>
```

Note that you will have to set the text and image dynamically through code (through some listener like onItemClick() or so).